# Delay in Google OneTap SignIn / SignUp popup display on Android

Tags: android, google-signin, google-identity, google-one-tap

I have implemented Google [Onetap SignIn](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-saved-credentials) in my application. Everything is working fine, the only issue that I am observing is that on certain devices the pop-up often takes 7-10 seconds to display. Especially in case of Sign-In popup.

Since I have multiple login options available in the app it might so happen that before I can show the user his last used google account to login (via OneTap popup), he gets enough time to click on any other option (eg, Facebook) & it becomes a poor experience.

Since this pop-up is displayed by play-services, I don't see how I can optimise this time taken.
As per the code, it seems the call to

```
contract
    .getOneTapClient()
    .beginSignIn(getSignInRequest(isRegistering))
```

is the one taking the most time. It seems the code that queries for user's on device Google Accounts.

Using below code structure. Adding for reference

```
    contract.getOneTapClient().beginSignIn(getSignInRequest(isRegistering))
            .addOnSuccessListener { result: BeginSignInResult ->
                try
                {
                    contract.startIntentSenderForResult(
                        result.pendingIntent.intentSender, requestCode,
                        null, 0, 0, 0, null)

                    successCallback?.onSuccess(isRegistering, "Rendering Popup")

                    val timeTaken = if(isRegistering) System.currentTimeMillis() - signUpTime
                    else System.currentTimeMillis() - signInTime
                    BBLogUtils.logWithTag(TAG, "Completed in ${timeTaken/1000.0}s")
                }
                catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException)
                {
                     failureCallback?.onFailure(isRegistering, e, ERROR_INTENT_SENDER_EXCEPTION)
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e: Exception ->
                // No saved credentials found.
                // OR Temporarily blocked due to too many canceled sign-in prompts.
                BBLogUtils.logWithTag(TAG, "Exception | registering=$isRegistering|rCount=$rCount | Error= ${e.message}")
                failureCallback?.onFailure(isRegistering, e, ERROR_NO_CREDENTIALS_FOUND)
            }
```

SignIn request object is the standard as prescribed by the docs

```
private fun getSignInRequest(isRegistering: Boolean): BeginSignInRequest
    {
        return BeginSignInRequest.builder()
            .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                .setSupported(true) // So that we receive the idToken in result
                .setServerClientId(contract.getGoogleAndroidClientId())
                /*
                 * true: for Registration ie. showing all accounts
                 * false: for return user signIn, ie. showing only previously used accounts
                 **/
                .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(!isRegistering)
                .build())
            .build()
    }
```

---

Another related question to this feature.
On the first launch of the app on device I saw this additional pop-up

[image]

Is there someway this can be skipped ?

Answer (score 0):

Answering 2nd part of my own query here.

After a lot search I still haven't bee able to find a workaround for skipping the process. Turns out that this popup is medium for play services to inform the user about the new sign-in experience.

I observed that if I installed another app using Google Onetap (eg. Reddit or PIntrest), the same pop-up appeared there as well. Also, its shown only once to a user, ie. if the pop up was shown in the Reddit app then it won't come in my app & vice-versa.

In addition, if you wan't to repro this scenario, you can clear the storage of **Google Play Services**. For some duration, it might show error: `16: App is not whitelisted`, but after a while, you will get the `How It Works` pop-up again.